# FFMPEG zoompan filter cut short my video and slowed it down

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG (version 4.0.2) to zoompan my video. My code is as below

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i overlay.png -ss 0 -t 10 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw+iw:ih+ih, zoompan=z='if(lte(pzoom,1.0),1.6,max(1.001,pzoom-0.004))':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='0':s=720x720, setsar=1 [v0];[1:v]crop=720:720,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=3:d=1[v1];[v0][v1] overlay [v]" -map "[v]" -f mp4 -preset ultrafast -y output.mp4
```

Essentially, what this code should do is slowly pan out from the center of my video, with a logo (overlay.png) fading in and out.

This input.mp4 is 10 seconds. With the above code, the final video duration is 10 seconds still. But its not the full footage, it is cut short and compensated with slow motion to make it 10 seconds still...

I need the final video to not be cut off at all. It should be the full footage and no slow motion effect.

Anyone has any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Input video is at: https://instantly.sg/photobooth/input.mp4

Overlay is at: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HABf.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: Share the input.

Comment: @Gyan sure. you can download it at https://instantly.sg/photobooth/input.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoompan filter defaults to 25 fps. You should set it to the input rate.

```
zoompan=z='if(lte(pzoom,1.0),1.6,max(1.001,pzoom-0.004))':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='0':s=720x720:fps=60000/1001
```

Comment: thanks! that works! I actually tried adding -r 60 to get frame rate of 60fps on the output video... But that didn’t work. Your method of setting fps=60000/1001 works though. Any reason why you used fps method instead of -r method?

Comment: I used the fps option inside zoompan because the filter will otherwise retime its output frames to 25 fps.